# OpenGl ES scrollable ListBox clipping problem

Tags: iphone, listbox, opengl-es, listboxitems

I am trying to create a generic list box in OpenGl ES (for the iPhone/iTouch) and I am running into a bit of a conundrum with clipping the ListBoxItems.  Each ListBoxItem object will know how to draw itself. The ListBox I am making will just draw each one after another.  But what if the number of items is larger than the ListBox?  I will need to be able to scroll (not a problem) the ListBoxItems up and down.  It will be a smooth scroll, so there will be times when a ListBoxItem will be half (or more, or less) visible and the other portion will be hidden because it is "outside" the ListBox area.  How do I get this clipping to work correctly when I am making my ListBox widget?

Thanks for any help or links you have,

~Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to crop your rendering use glScissor!

```
  void glScissor( GLint x,
          GLint y,
          GLsizei width,
          GLsizei height )
```

Comment: Don't forget to enable scissor testing with glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST); and disable once you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Gerald.  Also, thanks for the backup codelogic.